# OMNeT++ batch execution messes up result

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm using omnetpp 5.6.2 and inet 4.2.0 and some self-written code to simulate flooding algorithms and compare them against simple flooding. For this, I set up a parameter study with grids of hosts that range from 3x3 to 9x9. However, when I set up a batch execution that runs through all three algorithms, all grids and different amounts of neighboring nodes plus five different seeds for the random number generator, the result files start getting messed up.

I'm running a simulation on its own with the following parameters:
Routing: Multipoint Relaying
Separation between nodes: 700m
Grid size: 8x8
Seed-set: 0

I'm measuring the maximum delay between a frame sent and the last node to receive it, which should be around 200ms considering every node resends with a random delay between 0 and 15ms.

I'm getting the following output in the .sca file:

```
    attr seedset 0
    param **.IIntelliFloodModule.typename "\"MultipointInria\""
    param **.separationX 700m
    param **.separationY 700m
    ...
    scalar EightByEight.globalSeqNumListener #maxDelayMs 208.496
```

However, if I run the very same simulation in a batch of simulations, it gives me the following numbers:

```
    attr seedset 0
    itervar Routing "\"MultipointInria\""
    itervar netw EightByEight
    itervar sepX 700m
    itervar sepY 700m
    param **.IIntelliFloodModule.typename "\"MultipointInria\""
    param **.separationX 700m
    param **.separationY 700m
    ...
    scalar EightByEight.globalSeqNumListener #maxDelayMs 285916.716
```

Which does not make sense at all, since in an 8x8 grid a frame has to travel at the very maximum 15 nodes to the last one, which even if every node transmits after the maximum holding time of 15ms would be 15x15ms = 225ms.
All the other statistics in that file are completely messed up and don't make sense. Every batch different runs are messed up like this, and it is always at least twenty or so runs that don't make sense at all. If I run them individually however, the numbers make sense again.

TL;DR
Running simulations in batches messes with the output.

I found nothing on this on the internet, I've read the manual and the user guide up and down and I'm really hoping to find an answer to this here since I need this simulation for my bachelors thesis and running around 210 runs individually is not a feasible task to do. Dividing into smaller runs is not possible either, since the way I intend to evaluate the data would take a lot longer.

Comment: Sharing a reproducible example might help the community to help you.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, however the project is made of lots and lots of files and I don't know where exactly the problem lies. Every file depends on each other and the inet framework. Would it help to share the whole project, or the .ini and .Ned files, or what could I share to help the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Batch simulations are nothing more than single simulations executed one by one, so in theory a step in a batch should generate exactly the same output as running that simulation scenario alone.

Now I said in *theory*. For optimization purposes, several steps can be run sequentially but in the SAME process (to avoid the overhead of starting up the process. This can be useful when you run a lot of short simulations), however this assumes that simulation model is error free. no leaks, no uninitialized memory etc.

If you have an uninitialized variable, you may get a crash or a totally garbage output.

If you are running with `opp_runall`, try to specify `-b 1` on the command line forcing each and every runs into a separate process.